# Codeigniter logic of PC/tl/sc/pm email

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, logic

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
       (
        [PM] => 14
        [LD] => 578
        [TL] => 56
        [SC] => 67
        [PC] => 
       )
)
```

The above are just IDs of PC/PM/TL/LD. I will then use them in a database query to get their email IDs.

I want to use the following logic, where my email template should work like
PC in “To” and all the rest CC’ed.

- If no PC assigned, then TL in to email rest all in cc
- If no TL, then LD in to email rest all in cc
- If no LD, then PM  in to email rest all in cc
- If no PM, then SC in to email rest all in cc

Also I want to add email IDs to array. So if I start with:

```
Array ( 
    [PC] => 
    [TL] => 1109 
    [LD] => 838 
    [PM] => 715,824,694 
    [SC] => 727
)
```

I will perform this SQL ($user_sql):

```sql
SELECT id,email
FROM   new_login 
WHERE  id IN (1109,838,715,824,694,727) 
AND    status = 1
```

To output:

```
Array ( 
    [694] => a@exateam.com 
    [715] => b@gmail.com 
    [727] => c@gmail.com 
    [824] => d@gmail.com 
    [838] => e@gmail.com 
    [1109] => m@gmail.com 
)
```

Comment: What have you tried? what does your code example look like? what part is failing?  Try to give the readers more information

Comment: Which database do you use? And which functions do you use to connect and retrieve data (mysqli_ ? PDO ?).

Answer (score 0):

This code below will:

- order the given IDs according to the priority of the two-letter codes;
- create one list of IDs splitting multi-ID strings into separate array elements;
- query the database to receive the corresponding emails addresses
- store these email addresses in key/value pairs (ID/email) in the right array variable (**$to** or **$cc**)

You did not specify which database engine you use. This code assumes you use mysqli and you have a conection object named **$con**. The database part of the code is untested. But it should at least give you the idea how to proceed.

Comments in the code should clarify what is happening:

```
// Example data:
$data = Array (
   Array ("PM" => "715,824,694", "LD" => "838", "TL" => "1109", 
          "SC" => "727", "PC" => null)
);

// Define the priority order of the different two letter codes:
$order = array_flip(array("PC", "TL", "LD", "PM", "SC"));

// Iterate over the data
foreach ($data as $row) {
    // Order $row elements by priority and filter out empty values:
    $row = array_filter(array_merge($order, $row));
    // if nothing is left over, then skip this row
    if (count($row) == 0) continue;
    // Count the number of IDs in "TO" addressee:
    $to_count = count(explode(',', array_values($row)[0]));
    // Create one list of IDs and turn comma-separated items 
    // into separate array elements:
    $row = explode(',', implode(',', $row));
    // Initialise arrays that will receive the email addresses for TO / CC
    $to = array();
    $cc = array();
    // Retrieve email addresses from database.
    // You need a valid mysqli connection object: $con
    // Prepare SQL statement to avoid SQL injection, and produce
    // the right number of question marks in it:
    $query = "SELECT id,email FROM new_login WHERE status = 1
              AND id IN (" . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($row), '?')) . ") ";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query) or die($con->error());
    // Bind the ID values to prepared SQL statement
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $row);
    // Execute SQL query
    $stmt->execute();
    // Fetch result into array
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    while($email = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        // Check whether it concerns a TO or CC address:
        if (array_search($email["id"], $row) < $to_count) {
            $to[$email["id"]] = $email["email"];
        } else {
            $cc[$email["id"]] = $email["email"];
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
    // use $to and $cc to send email
    // ...
}
```

Comment: what if i get multiple values like
Array
(
    [PC] => 
    [TL] => 645
    [LD] => 838
    [PM] => 715,824,694
    [SC] => 727
)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `[PM] => 715,824,694`? Is it the string `"715,824,694"`, or is it an array like `[PM] => array(715, 824, 694)`?  Note that all your values are currently numbers, it would be strange to see a string or array appear where a number is expected. Can you clarify?

Comment: Also, please specify what kind of result you expect. Do you want those combined IDs (tell me whether they are string or array) to be separated into numbers? Do you then still need these two-letter words (PM, TL, ...), or is it OK to then just provide an array of ID for TO, and an array for CC, like `$cc = array(838, 715, 824, 694, 727)` for your example?

Comment: string at key PM of an array

Comment: You mean OR an array? And what is the expected result? See my last comment. Is that the output you want?

Comment: yes 
$to = array(645 )  
$cc = array(838, 715, 824, 694, 727)

Comment: Also i want to add email ids to array 
Array
(
    [PC] => 
    [TL] => 1109
    [LD] => 838
    [PM] => 715,824,694
    [SC] => 727
)

------------- $user_sql : SELECT id,email FROM new_login 
                            WHERE id IN (1109,838,715,824,694,727) AND status = 1 -------- 

Array
(
    [694] => a@exateam.com
    [715] => b@gmail.com
    [727] => c@gmail.com
    [824] => d@gmail.com
    [838] => e@gmail.com
    [1109] => m@gmail.com
)

Comment: I extended my code to deal with comma-separated strings in the data (like `[PM] => 715,824,694`), and added some untested code to read email addresses from your table and store them in two arrays: **$to** and **$cc**. Both are arrays with key/value pairs, where key is ID, and value is email.